# Find the IP and Username from a huge text file

Tags: powershell

```
#NAM=127.0.0.1 #PRT="HomeServer:Ping Test"#HID=100#DEP=-1#DPS=5#GRP=G00000027#REM=""#UID=6038#ACT=T#LOL=F#FOL=F#VIA="#DE=__LAN__#KA=F#"#LDEFUP=5/16/2019 10:44:39 PM#LDEWHO=#TPL=F#MUT=#MFR=#RUSE=F...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to read and act on this: [ask]

Comment: More information is needed in order for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to learn Powershell so I will help you out. Next time please provide a valid question.

What you are trying to do is use Regular Expression to search for Ips.

Powershell is using the .Net Framework. Calling a class is as easy as using `[Class Here]`

So we will call the regex class and then search for IP addresses in a string.

In this case i wrote a quick function to do this task

```
function Find-IPAddresses([string]$Data){
    [regex]::Matches($File, "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)") | %{
        $_.value
    }
}

$Info = @"
#NAM=127.0.0.1 #PRT="HomeServer:Ping Test"#HID=100#DEP=-1#DPS=5#GRP=G00000027#REM=""#UID=6038#ACT=T#LOL=F#FOL=F#VIA="#DE=__LAN__#KA=F#"#LDEFUP=5/16/2019 10:44:39 PM#LDEWHO=#TPL=F#MUT=#MFR=#RUSE=F..
"@

Find-IPAddresses -Data $Info
```

it will return `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I am sorry for asking a question in not a right manner. I will try to be more specific while asking next time. I also need to get the hostname and IP both. The thing which i have pasted that value is coming in my array index 0 array [0]. I need IP and Hostname both and everytime they would be at a same place.
#NAM=127.0.0.1 #PRT="HomeServer

Comment: $strReference = Get-Content "C:\Users\ssharma258\Desktop\TEST\test.txt"
$strDifference = Get-Content "C:\Users\ssharma258\Desktop\TEST\TEST1.txt"
$array = @(Compare-Object $strReference $strDifference)
$array[0] | out-file testing.txt
$array[0]